# Can I access Terraform locals as a map that can be iterated?

Tags: terraform, infrastructure-as-code

I am building a terraform `module` for redis and I am looking to create a config hash of the `aws_memorydb_cluster` config so that I can trigger a `random_string` keeper to generate new resource names when the config changes and terraform forces new resource.

```
locals {
  redis_cluster_name_prefix   = "${var.short_name_prefix}-${var.env}-redis"
  parameter_group_name_prefix = "${var.short_name_prefix}-${var.env}-redis-param-group"
  subnet_group_name_prefix    = "${var.short_name_prefix}-${var.env}-redis-subnet-group"

  auto_minor_version_upgrade = true
  tls_enabled                = true

  redis_config_hash = base64sha256(join(", ", flatten([for item in map(locals) : [for key, value in item : "${key}=${value}"]])))
}

resource "random_string" "random_str" {
  length  = 5
  special = false
  lower   = true
  upper   = false
  keepers = {
    redis_config_hash = local.redis_config_hash
  }
}
```

I am looking to access the `locals` block as a map but I get this error instead.

```
╷
│ Error: Invalid reference
│ 
│   on modules/redis/locals.tf line 9, in locals:
│    9:   redis_config_hash = base64sha256(join(", ", flatten([for item in locals : [for key, value in item : "${key}=${value}"]])))
│ 
│ A reference to a resource type must be followed by at least one attribute access, specifying the resource name.
```

It would be great if I could access the `locals` as a map within Terraform so some cool iterations would be possible. Feel free to point me to other workarounds if you have seen anything similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

local values created by locals block [can only be referenced with an object](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/values/locals) called `local`, this object cannot be accessed directly. You can simple create a local map and use its keys to create your value, for example:

```
locals {
  redis_config = {
    redis_cluster_name_prefix   = "${var.short_name_prefix}-${var.env}-redis"
    parameter_group_name_prefix = "${var.short_name_prefix}-${var.env}-redis-param-group"
    subnet_group_name_prefix    = "${var.short_name_prefix}-${var.env}-redis-subnet-group"

    auto_minor_version_upgrade = true
    tls_enabled                = true
  }

  redis_config_hash = base64sha256(join(", ", flatten([for key, value in local.redis_config : "${key}=${value}"])))
}
```